# How to convert ping command to string on MacOS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I need to convert the ping command to string on MacOS terminal for the following task:

I recently started using the telegram-send command which is basically a way to send messagess on telegram via the MacOS Terminal. I want to use the terminal to send the result of my ping to my telegram account (to basically monitor its uptime).

This is how the telegram-send command works:

```
telegram-send "hello world"
```

and I'd like to it function in a way that I could get this result:

```
telegram-send ping 192.168.1.1
```

but obviously the command above wouldn't work because whatever comes in front of telegram-send will be sent as string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you considered using telegram-cli - which lets you send yourself a file (since ping is multi-line output?)?

Comment: I honestly couldn't get it to work and didn't find a good tutorial on how I could use it on Mac. If you have any suggestions I'd love to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the shell you're using, you can do it like this:

```
telegram-send "$(ping -c1 192.168.1.1)"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I get this error when using the code above:
% telegram-send $(ping -c1 192.168.1.165)
usage: telegram-send [-h] [--format {text,markdown,html}] [--stdin] [--pre]
                     [--disable-web-page-preview] [--silent] [-c]
                     [--configure-channel] [--configure-group]
                     [-f FILE [FILE ...]] [-i IMAGE [IMAGE ...]]
                     [-s STICKER [STICKER ...]]
                     [--animation ANIMATION [ANIMATION ...]]
                     [--video VIDEO [VIDEO ...]] [--audio AUDIO [AUDIO ...]]

Comment: I think you forgot the error?

Comment: [-l LOCATION [LOCATION ...]]
                     [--caption CAPTION [CAPTION ...]] [--config CONF] [-g]
                     [--file-manager] [--clean] [--timeout TIMEOUT]
                     [--version]
                     [message ...]
telegram-send: error: unrecognized arguments: --- 192.168.1.165 ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.807/3.807/3.807/0.000 ms

Comment: Sorry it was too long! I had to chop it in half.

Comment: Try the updated command now.

Comment: That's it!!!! You're the best. Thank you so so so much

Comment: The quotes are important ..